# URL parameters on javascript

Tags: javascript, spring

I´m making a call using javascript and I would like to send an array:

```
var selected = [];
selected=getAllEnginesIdsSelected();
    console.log("selected: "+selected);
    $.getJSON('/call/' + selected,
            function(myList) {
```

The funcion that I use in Javascript to retrieve array is:

```
function getAllEnginesIdsSelected() {

        var selected = [];

        $("input:checkbox[id^='engine_']:checked").each(function(){
            var ele=$(this)[0].id;
            selected.push(ele);
        });

        return selected;

    }
```

Console.log retrieves selected: 2,5

In MVC Controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/call/{selected}")
public List<List<myList>> myCall(@RequestParam(value="selected[]") String[] selected){
```

I gives an error. I don´t want to use AJAX. This is posible to send?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, getAllEnginesIdsSelected() is always going to return an empty array.

Comment: You don't want to use Ajax you say? $.getJSON uses Ajax.

Comment: Btw you can totally drop this: `selected = [];` in the first code snippet. You can directly assign the method to the variable.

Comment: I didn ´t know Tom. David W, I edited the code.

Comment: You can't use getJSON to send data. You'd be better off using $.post().

Comment: `var ele=$(this)[0].id;` is the same as `var ele = this.id` only more complicated and expensive (create jQuery object from DOM node, unwrap the jQuery object to get the DOM node, access DOM attribute vs access DOM attribute)

Comment: I dont want to send data, I want to receive data from URL

Comment: Tom, I tried this code before, but with a simple id

Comment: Your url is going to look like -> `/call/1,2`  to me that just looks odd, I would expected something like `/call?sel=1,2`  and then MVC controller could look for the `sel` query param, and then you could do a Sring.split on this sel param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected` is an array, which you are joining to a string in the URL. Try something like `$.getJSON('/call/?selected=[' + selected.join(',')]`

Comment: I make toString of array and I sent the values :)